# problem in salesforce lightning design system menu after Rerender the panel

Tags: visualforce, rerender, slds

i'm using lightning design system in custom visual force page with controller and apex re render, rest of the LDS component  working fine after rerender but Menu component lost the styling and taging. i did not use remote object but use custom controller. so there is any work around to fix the issue?  here is my summary code . `

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">    

    <head>
        <link href="https://code.ionicframework.com/ionicons/2.0.1/css/ionicons.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
        <apex:stylesheet value="{!URLFOR($Resource.SLDS0102, 'assets/styles/salesforce-lightning-design-system-vf.css')}" />
    </head>

    <body>    

        <!-- REQUIRED SLDS WRAPPER -->
        <div class="slds">    
            <apex:outputPanel id="panel1">

                <apex:form >
                    <div class="slds-m-left--x-large">   
                        <div class="slds-dropdown-trigger ">
                            <button type="button" class="slds-button slds-button--icon-border-filled" aria-haspopup="true" style="    width: 60px;">
                                <i class="ion ion-information-circled"> </i>
                                <i class="ion ion-arrow-down-b  "> </i>



                                <span class="slds-assistive-text">Show More</span>
                            </button>
                            <div class="slds-dropdown slds-dropdown--left slds-dropdown--actions slds-dropdown--menu slds-nubbin--top-right">
                                <ul class="slds-dropdown__list" role="menu">

                                    <li id="menu1" href="#" class="slds-dropdown__item">
                                        <a href="javascript:void(0)"  role="menuitemradio"   >
                                            <p class="slds-truncate">
                                                <i class="ion  ion-checkmark  slds-m-right--x-small" ></i>Value1 </p>
                                        </a>
                                    </li>

                                    <li id="menu2" href="#" class="slds-dropdown__item">
                                        <a href="javascript:void(0)" role="menuitemradio"   >
                                            <p class="slds-truncate">
                                                <i class="ion  ion-checkmark-circled slds-m-right--x-small" ></i> Value2</p>
                                        </a>
                                    </li>

                                </ul>
                            </div>


                        </div>  
                        <div class="slds-m-bottom--large"></div>  
                        <apex:commandButton reRender="panel1" value="ReRender" styleClass="slds-button slds-button--neutral"/>
                    </div>
                </apex:form>
            </apex:outputPanel>


        </div>


    </body>
</html>
```

`

Display Result

[image]

Comment: Could you post an example of the HTML after the rerender? This can be pulled from your browser's developer tools. Knowing how the HTML has changed will help us troubleshoot this.

Comment: post your output design screenshot

Comment: i just check the html after rerender and compare with before rerender same markup generated

Comment: can you please see the screenshot

Answer (score 2):

The problem is because when you rerender visualforce is replacing the  tag with  tag. Try replacing the  tag with  tag in oncomplete event with a js library like jquery. It has a replaceWith function.